# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - Google chrome issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typeerror

Can someone please help in resolving this - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. - error while testing asp.net application in chrome

Code snippet:

```
 if (myTooltip)
 {
        myTooltip.SetVariable('enterhere', StatusContent);
            //Error occurs here
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure the "myTooltip" object has the "SetVariable" method?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking to see if myTooltip is defined, but you are assuming that SetVariable is defined.

```
if (myTooltip && myTooltip.SetVariable)
```

Comment: Hi...this gives JScript runtime error in IE 'Object does not support this property or method '...Can u plz help?